# Error al añadir una llave foranea a los datos de un modelForm NULL constraint failed

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

He querido añadirle la llave foranea a mi tabla de ingresos que se relaciona con x cliente pero los campos se llenan desde el formulario y la relación tiene que hacerse automática para facilidad del cliente, esto lo menciono ya que he visto que otras preguntas parecidas la solucion es un select con los clientes pero en este caso no podría hacerlo así.

Este es mi modelo

```
class fuenteIngresos(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    cliente = models.ForeignKey(ClienteInfoPersonal, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    fuente = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=fuentes)
    datosFuente = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name="Fecha Creacion")
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, verbose_name="Fecha Actualizado")
    readonly_fields = ('id','fk', 'created', 'updated')
```

Uso este modelo para crear un formulario y este es mi formulario

```
class formularioIngresos(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = fuenteIngresos
        fields = '__all__'
        exclude = ('cliente',)
```

Y esta sería mi vista

```
def cliente(request, ID):
    cliente = ClienteInfoPersonal.objects.get(id = ID)
    if request.method == "GET":
        
        formIngresos = formularioIngresos
        try:
            ingresos = fuenteIngresos.objects.all().filter(cliente = cliente)
            return render(request, 'core/cliente.html', {'cliente': cliente, 'ingresos': ingresos, 'form1': formIngresos})
        except:
            return render(request, 'core/cliente.html', {'cliente': cliente, 'form1': formIngresos})
    else:
        formIngresos = formularioIngresos(request.POST)
        if formIngresos.is_valid():
            #Aqui es donde me marca error
            formIngresos.cliente = cliente
            formIngresos.save()
            print("Guardo")
            return redirect(reverse('formularios')+'?ok')
        else:
            print(formIngresos.errors)
```

El error que me marca es NOT `NULL constraint failed: core_fuenteingresos.cliente_id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error sucede por que tu modelo indica que el campo cliente es requerido. Para poder modificar el objeto antes de que sea creado en la base debes de usar el parametro commit=False para crear el objeto de manera local sin insertarlo en la base y entonces así poder llenar el campo cliente antes de guardarlo, se hace de la siguiente manera:

```
if formIngresos.is_valid():
    ingresos = formIngresos.save(commit=False) # Almacenar el objeto fuenteIngresos en una variable
    ingresos.cliente = cliente # Asignar el cliente
    ingresos.save() # Guardar los cambios en la base
    return redirect(reverse('formularios')+'?ok')
else:
    print(formIngresos.errors)
```

Si te fue útil esta respuesta márcala como aceptada para personas que tengan la misma duda.